# Can a Less mixin apply special rules to certain element types?

Tags: css, less

I have a mixin for button styling that I apply to both button-styled `a` tags and actual `button` tags, but I'm using *flexbox* vertical centering and this is broken in some versions of Webkit.

For example, here's how I might do it in Stylus, but i need to accomplish the same thing in Less:

```
.container {  
  btn(width) {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: width;
    height: 50px;

    // How can I do this part, somehow, in Less?
    ../ button^[1..-1] {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }

  .btn {
    btn(100px);
  }
}
```

The above is how I'm doing it in Stylus but I am hoping to find another way to get around the Less limitation. I tried appending to the selector, for example, `:not(:not(button))` but this doesn't seem to be supported by browsers .

Comment: Ok, I just read the Stylus documentation and you seem to be looking to insert a selector (button) in the middle of the parent (which is `.container .btn`). This is currently not possible with Less.

Comment: Harry, that's how I'm doing it in Stylus but I was hoping to find another way to get around the Less limitation. I tried appending to the selector, for example, :not(:not(button)) but this doesn't seem to be supported by browsers ;-)

Comment: On my react project I ended up appending a child div to all my buttons and styling it, so I can use the same style for all my elements. Try to not rely on very specific and complex selectors. They will drive you crazy later. Instead, write meaningful markup and apply simple classes to it (BEM style)

Answer (score 1):

Less (or any pre-processor) doesn't have any way to know what type of element is being represented by the selector and hence they cannot generate such rules without being specifically instructed by the developer. Also, Less doesn't support targeting a specific part of a parent selector and modifying it. So there is no direct conversion for the Stylus code given in question.

---

Having said that, there are a few alternate options that can be adopted to generate an output similar to that of the Stylus code.

**Option 1:** (Using CSS `:not` selector)

We can use the CSS `:not` (negation) selector to apply the flexbox styling only to `.btn` element that are not `button` elements.

[The support for `:not` is available in latest versions of all browsers and IE supports it from 9+.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

```css
.container {  
  .btn-mixin(@width) {
    display: inline-block; /* default display is inline block */
    width: @width;
    height: 50px;
    &:not(button){ /* override for elements that are not buttons */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
  .btn {
    .btn-mixin(100px);
  }
}
```

This can't be written with the default display as flex because negation selector can be appended at the end whereas an element type selector cannot be. Below is a demo with the compiled CSS.

```css
.container .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.container .btn:not(button) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href='#' class='btn'>Hello!</a>
  <a href='#' class='btn'>we</a>
  <a href='#' class='btn'>are</a>
  <a href='#' class='btn'>some</a>
  <a href='#' class='btn'>links</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class='btn'>Hello!</button>
  <button class='btn'>we</button>
  <button class='btn'>are</button>
  <button class='btn'>some</button>
  <button class='btn'>buttons</button>
</div>
```

---

**Option 2:** (Using Less parameterized mixins)

This is ***not an option that I recommend***. Option 1 is in my opinion more straight-forward and simple. I am throwing this into the answer just to show conditional behavior can be achieved in Less. It uses the ***guards*** feature to check what the value of an argument (`@elType`) is and then apply styles.

```css
.container {  
  .btn-mixin(@width; @elType: anchor) {
    & when not (@elType = anchor){
      display: inline-block;
    }
    & when (@elType = anchor){
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    width: @width;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .btn {
    .btn-mixin(100px);
  }
  button.btn {
    .btn-mixin(200px, button);
  }
}
```

---

**Why doesn't** `:not(:not(button))` **work?**

This selector wouldn't work (not yet atleast) because as of now, the [negation `:not` selector accepts only simple selectors as arguments](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation). `:not(button)` (which is the argument to the outer negation) is not a simple selector.